# Providing to consumers InputStream from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I have this problem that I've stumbled upon recently.
I am using `ProcessBuilder` to call external process. Process can return either human readable string, or compressed content.
 Code looks like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
return p.getInputStream();
```

This is ok for small input, but for larger one process blocks, waiting for the buffer to be emptied. Consumer code is already implemented, so is there another way to retrun from this function with an `InputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is process wont be able to write to the input stream if the consuming thread doesn't consume the values in the input stream beyond the buffer size.

if you dont want to change the consumer code , one solution i can think of is to read all the process input stream in to a StringBuffer and then return the input stream to the StringBuffer instead of the process input stream.

```
InputStream startProcess() {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    String dummy;
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
       void run(){
           while(dummy = pb.getInputStream().readLine() != null) 
           buffer.append(dummy);
       }
    }).start();
    p.waitFor();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toString().getBytes());
}
```

PS: we are reading the inputstream in a different thread to avoid blocking the main thread for execution.